# React Native Background Actions

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-background-fetch

I am developing a React native application. There is a request in the application that I need to send every 10 seconds. But I am trying to send this request when the application is in the background or closed.

I used the React-native-background-action package, but when I put it in the background, it stops the process. I would be happy if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, install the package:

   ```
   npm install react-native-background-fetch
   ```
2. import the package in your .js file

   ```
   import BackgroundFetch from 'react-native-background-fetch';

   componentDidMount() {
   BackgroundFetch.configure(
    {
      minimumFetchInterval: 10, // The task will be executed every 10 seconds
      stopOnTerminate: false, // The task will continue to run even if the app is terminated
      startOnBoot: true, // The task will start when the device is booted
    },
    () => {
      // Your code to send the request here
      console.log('Background task executed');

      // Remember to call BackgroundFetch.finish() to indicate that the task has completed
      BackgroundFetch.finish();
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log('Background task error', error);
    },
   );

   BackgroundFetch.start();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I have to do it this way or can I write it using useEffect? Also, do I need to edit the Android files?

Comment: yes instead of componentDidMount use useEffect & checkout react-native-background-fetch installation process

Comment: `minimumFetchInterval` value unit is `minute`. So `minimumFetchInterval: 10` means every 10 minutes. Though the `minimumFetchInterval` minimum value is `15`